# JVM Tuning for Atlassian applications on Large Ec2 instance

Tags: jvm, artifactory, bamboo, confluence

Can anyone help me to understand what JVM memory size I can use for Large Ec2 Instances?

I am working on five applications - Atlassian apps (Bamboo, Bitbucket, Confluence, Jira) and Artifactory?

For Jira Application I found information online but no for other apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Large EC2 instance is slightly ambiguous, so I'll assume you're referring to the [general purpose](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) category, which has 2vCPUs and 8GiB of RAM.

The [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS#InstallingonLinuxSolarisorMacOS-SettingJavaMemoryParameters) advises you to reserve at least 512MB for JFrog Artifactory, with the recommended minimal JVM parameters being:

```
-server -Xms512m -Xmx2g -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC
```

Based on the number of developers you're planning to service with JFrog Artifactory, you'll need to update the `-Xmx` parameter. The "[Recommended Hardware](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/System+Requirements#SystemRequirements-RecommendedHardware)" table in the documentation, will give you an overview of the suggested amount of RAM based on the number of developers.

Comment: Thanks for your response....I am looking for C5.2xlarge ec2 instance  vCPU=8   16Gib of RAM

Comment: ah awesome! The recommended hardware table should give you some insight into what the max number of devs is that such a machine could handle (please note that it isn't an exact science, so the numbers might be a little different).